# How to include an applet(with 2 class files) in html page using <object> tag?

Tags: java, applet

I have a requirement which needs 2 .class files in a single jar. In legacy code, the archive has only 1 class file  tag was used to include applet in the html page. Now, I am confused with how to specify the 2nd class file URI inside the object tag. I want to know , how to specify the second class in the 
param name ="code" ..... tag.

Below is the code we use now.

```
<object id="appletId" name="appletId" type="application/x-java-applet" height="1" width="1">
    <param name="codebase_lookup" value="false" />
    <param name="code" value="com.test.appletTest.AppletClassOne" />
    <param name="codebase" value="/AppletTestWeb/applets" />
    <param name="archive" value="AppletTest.jar" />
    <param name="java_arguments" value="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" />
</object>
```

Comment: Have you tired a second object tag?

Comment: @Stefan... Thank you for the response...We have tried that approach and its working. But , we are looking for an approach where we wouldn't need a second object tag and have some means of specifying the second class within the existing object tag itself.

Comment: I think an Applet can only have one starter class.

Comment: @Stefan is correct.  To load two applets from the same Jar, would need **two** `object` (or `applet`) elements.  Each instance of those HTML tags was designed to load a single applet.